# GCC C: Is there an equivalent to exit() that calls __attribute__(cleanup) functions?

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I read that the functions registered with `cleanup` will not be called when the program terminates early through `exit()` or `longjmp()`. Is there any function that I can call that works similarly to `exit()` (meaning I can use it to terminate the program from functions other than `main()`, such as signal handlers) but which will call all of the registered `cleanup` functions? If I was using C++ I could just use `throw()` (since `cleanup` functions are called during stack unwinding), but I need this to be in C.

Comment: Well, there is `atexit()`

Comment: This may be helpful: https://github.com/psevon/exceptions-and-raii-in-c

Answer (score 2):

In the glibc implementation, `pthread_exit` performs stack unwinding and terminates the program if the current thread is the only thread. The downside is that you cannot specify the exit status.

To get cleanup functions to execute during stack unwinding, you need to build with `-fexceptions`.

(For glibc before 2.34, you may have to link with `-lpthread` to get the stack-unwinding variant of `pthread_exit`.)

Comment: [Are you sure it calls the cleanup functions?](https://godbolt.org/z/fb3hc4xYM) Do you have documentation for this?

Comment: You need to build with `-fexceptions` and force linking with `-lpthread` (for glibc 2.33 and earlier).

Comment: [Confirmed.](https://godbolt.org/z/8fs6sjGqG) You should cite and link to documentation for this.

Comment: `pthread_exit()` is good, but I really would like to be able to return a nonzero exit code.